# Hide And Show Button in Visual Basic

Tags: button, visual-studio-2012, show-hide

Greet, I new with Visual Basic and I wan't to ask something. Is it possible to make hide and show button with only one button. For example, this 'X' button could show or hide this 'A' button without using another button to show and to hide button? I already learn to do this using Checked property as a toggle only like this coding.

```
If mnuViewTextboxes.Checked = True Then 

   TextBox1.Visible = True 

Else 

   TextBox1.Visible = False 

End If
```

Comment: Sure: A.Visible = Not A.Visible

Comment: Just declare like that sir?

Answer (score -1):

add  timer to your form and do something like

`Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If  mnuViewTextboxes.Checked = True Then
            TextBox1.Visible = True`

```
    ElseIf mnuViewTextboxes.Checked = false Then
        TextBox1.Visible = False 
    End If






End Sub
```